# Why is bash/ogr outputting shapefiles into individual folders within the output directory?

Tags: bash, loops, shapefile, ogr

I'm new to bash/ogr and can't seem to figure out why this loop outputs shapefiles into individual folders within the output directory. Here is my code:

```
BASE=/home/user/J/cacti_mexico
INPUT=/home/user/J/cacti_mexico/shps
OUTPUT=/home/user/J/cacti_mexico/mexshps
SCRIPT=/home/user/J/cacti_mexico/scripts

cd $INPUT

while read line; do 
  echo $line 
  for file in $INPUT/$line.shp ; do 
    ogr2ogr $OUTPUT/$line $file
  done
done < $SCRIPT/cacti_mexico_names.txt
```

The `cacti_mexico_names.txt` file contains a list of species names which are picked up from the input directory once `.shp` has been concatenated onto the end of it. If anyone can tell me how to get all the shapefiles from `ogr2ogr` to output into `$OUTPUT` directly, that would be great.

**Update:**

ogr2ogr treats its first argument as the name of a directory so the fixed code reads as:

```
ogr2ogr $OUTPUT $file
```

Comment: Isn't your inner `for`-loop equivalent to just `ogr2ogr $OUTPUT/$line $input/$line.shp`? (I mean, unless you have whitespace or asterisks or whatnot in `$line`, in which case you have bigger problems.)

Comment: It appears that `ogr2ogr` treats its first argument as the name of a directory, not the name of a file. Would `ogr2ogr $OUTPUT $file` work?

Comment: Chepner, you are correct. Thanks for spotting this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Since feature requests to [mark a comment as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82099/answering-comment-answered-questions) remain declined, I copy the above solution here.*

It appears that ogr2ogr treats its first argument as the name of a directory, not the name of a file. Would ogr2ogr $OUTPUT $file work? – chepner